# "react-native link react-native-sound" doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add react-native-sound npm package,but I have to run this "react-native link react-native-sound"
But I get this error:

warn Calling react-native link [packageName] is deprecated in favor of autolinking. It will be removed in the next major release.
Autolinking documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

Comment: If you are using RN version 0.60 and above, packages are autolinked. There is no need to run `react-native link`

Comment: @SagarShakya Yes, but I get this error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid") and when I google that, people say you should run that.

Comment: If that is the case, you can just ignore the warning.